# Repaintng a JPanel when a key is pressed. (java)

Tags: java, keylistener, repaint

I'm working on a Swing application in Java and i can't update my JPanel when a key is pressed...

This is the JFrame

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PixelDraw {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    //SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new DrawingPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And this is my panel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int scale = 5;
    private int bits = 8 * scale;
    private int cols = 32;

    //Selection rectangle:
    private int sX = 0;
    private int sY = 0;
    private int sWidth = 1;
    private int sHeight = 1;

    private Color BackFill = new Color(140, 140, 140);
    private Color BackBorder = new Color(70, 70, 70);

    public DrawingPanel() {
        //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        addKeyListener(this);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                //On Click:

            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                //On Dragg:
            }
        });

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            sY = (sY == 0) ? sY :  sY-1;
            if (evt.isControlDown()) {
                sWidth = (sY == 0) ? sWidth : sWidth+1;
            }
        }

        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            sY = (sY == cols) ? sY :  sY+1;
            if (evt.isControlDown()) {
                sWidth = (sY == cols) ? sWidth : sWidth+1;
            }
        }

        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            sX = (sX == 0) ? sX :  sX-1;
            if (evt.isControlDown()) {
                sWidth = (sY == 0) ? sWidth : sHeight+1;
            }
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            sX = (sX == cols) ? sX :  sX+1;
            if (evt.isControlDown()) {
                sWidth = (sY == cols) ? sWidth : sHeight+1;
            }
        }

        this.repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 800);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       

        //paint Background
        for(int x = 0; x <= (cols-1) * bits; x += bits) {
            for(int y = 0; y <= (cols-1) * bits; y += bits){
                g.setColor(BackBorder);
                g.fillRect(x, y, bits, bits);
                g.setColor(BackFill);
                g.fillRect(x+(1*scale), y+(1*scale), bits-(1*scale), bits-(1*scale));
            }
        }

        //paint selection
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(sX*bits, sY*bits, (sWidth*bits)+(scale-1), (sHeight*bits)+(scale-1));
    }  
}
```

So, what it should do is move the red rectangle (like a selection) when arrows are pressed... or grow the selection when ctrl+arrows is pressed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a common problem with KeyListeners -- that of lack of component focus. For a KeyListener to function, the listened to component must be both focusable and have the user focus, neither of which is true for your application.

A quick fix is to make your JPanel focusable via `setFocusable(true)` and then gain focus via `requestFocusInWindow()`.

```
public DrawingPanel() {
  addKeyListener(this);
  setFocusable(true);
  requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

But this will fail as soon as another component, such as a JButton or text component, is added to your GUI and steals the focus. A better long term solution is to use Key Bindings.

---

**Edit**

Please check out [the Key Bindings Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Also if you search this site for my posts with key bindings, you'll see some OK examples. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20body%3akey%20bindings).

Comment: I started this project some hours ago but i have lot of features to add to it so probably doing everything the right way isn't a bad idea... Could you link me a tutorial for a good way to use "Key Bindings" ? :)

Comment: +1 @XandruDavid, `i have lot of features to add to it so probably doing everything the right way isn't a bad idea...` - I like that attitude. Take a look at the "trail" link from the tutorial to find other topics of interest about Swing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, i'll be back if i'll have any problem with key bindings..